# How to rate my app on Google play direct by App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-play

I am developing in ionic 3 and would like to know if there is a possibility to create a modal to classify the App periodically (every 15 days) without having to go to Google play? Can someone give me a hint on how to do something like this or if there is any Api or component in the ionic that does this

Comment: No. You could show `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<yourpackage>` embedded somewhere but users may not be logged in. Messing with the rating system can also get you easily suspended.

Comment: How do other applications use this function? Unless this function is stored in a database for analysis on the app and not directly linked to google play's ranking

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you're trying to achieve. Linking to the play store url will open the play store app on an android device, that's essentially what all apps do. Your app can open the play store in the right spot for users, it can't do the voting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe yo can try with the `Ionic-Native` Plugin `App-Rate`

**Here´s the official link**

> https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-rate/

and try set `Custom Preference` and `Full Setup` here´s the link to the Repo (same that the plugin)

> https://github.com/pushandplay/cordova-plugin-apprate#full-setup

hopefully it will help you. :D